# Unable to connect to the remote server (ftp works in development but not in production)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm working on an asp.net mvc web application that is on a shared server hosted by web.com. It runs on IIS 7 and .NET 4.0.

I'm getting the error "*[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server] System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()*" when my popup form loads it's dropdown list with names of directories in my ftp site. I'm able to run my application and connect to the ftp in development (using visual studio 2019). And I'm able to telnet to the ftp (default port 21).

Controller code:

```
[NoCache]
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    ViewData["Folders"] = GetFolders();
    return View();
}

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetFolders()
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Timeout = -1;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
    List<SelectListItem> folders = new List<SelectListItem>();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string names = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();

    var folderList =
        new List<string>(names.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToList());
    folders = folderList.ConvertAll(a =>
    {
        return new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = a.ToString(),
            Value = a.ToString(),
            Selected = false
        };
    });
    return folders;
}
```

This is the ftpwebrequest log with the original ftpUrl:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [11124] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [27548]
FtpWebRequest#25592066::.ctor(ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/ftp/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [27548]
FtpWebRequest#25592066::GetResponse(Method=NLST.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [27548] Exception in
FtpWebRequest#25592066::GetResponse - Unable to connect to the remote server.
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

This is the ftpwebrequest log when I change the ftpUrl to root:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [11124] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [20756] 
FtpWebRequest#17494990::.ctor(ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [20756] 
FtpWebRequest#17494990::GetResponse(Method=NLST.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [20756] Exception in 
FtpWebRequest#17494990::GetResponse - Unable to connect to the remote server.
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

This is the ftpwebrequest log when I change the ftpUrl to an IP address:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [50288] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [25964]
FtpWebRequest#40369685::.ctor(ftp://111.222.333.44/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [25964]
FtpWebRequest#40369685::GetResponse(Method=NLST.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [25964] Exception in
FtpWebRequest#40369685::GetResponse - Unable to connect to the remote server.
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

I'm new to C# and asp.net mvc so please bear with me. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you run telnet from the server when your app is deployed in production? If you're able to connect from your dev environment it doesn't mean that from production you'll be able.

Comment: Thank you for replying! When I type "telnet ftp.mywebsite.com 21" on my client computer I get "220 Microsoft FTP Service".

Comment: I am able to log into "ftp ftp.mywebsite.com" and list the directories by typing "ftp> ls" in the command line. I also am able to connect and view directories using a web browser. FileZilla works too. I will try to work the log file in my code and let you know what I get.

Comment: Have you checked that your code gets the expected hostname (ftp.mywebsite.com) in the variable `ftpUrl` ? Alternative try with the IP address.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this is the log: System.Net Information: 0 : [30212] Current OS installation type is 'Server'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [4960] FtpWebRequest#27524287::.ctor(ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/ftp/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4960] FtpWebRequest#27524287::GetResponse(Method=NLST.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4960] RAS supported: True
System.Net Error: 0 : [4960] Exception in FtpWebRequest#27524287::GetResponse - Unable to connect to the remote server.
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: @FrankNielsen Thank you for replying. My ftpUrl points to "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/ftp/". I will try changing it to just the root. And if that doesn't work I'll try the IP address and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that FTP ports are filtered for connections opened from your server.

One option could be to open a terminal on that server (not from your computer or from your dev environment) and try to run telnet to the ftp endpoint.

Anyway if you can't try that and also to be sure you're using the proper FTP endpoint, you could replace your current code for `GetFolders` with the following that is going to test connectivity:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetFolders()
{
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = -1;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        List<SelectListItem> folders = new List<SelectListItem>();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string names = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        var folderList =
            new List<string>(names.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .ToList());
        folders = folderList.ConvertAll(a =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = a.ToString(),
                Value = a.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            };
        });
        return folders;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var hostname = (new Uri(ftpUrl)).Host;
        bool pingable = false;
        using (Ping pinger = new Ping())
        {
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = pinger.Send(hostname);
                pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception pEx)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error pinging {hostname}: {pEx.ToString()}", pEx);
            }
        }

        if (pingable)
        {
            using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient())
            {
                tc.Connect(hostname, 20);
                bool stat = tc.Connected;
                if (!stat)
                    throw new Exception($"Cannot connect to {hostname} on port 20", ex);

                tc.Close();
            }
            using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient())
            {
                tc.Connect(hostname, 21);
                bool stat = tc.Connected;
                if (!stat)
                    throw new Exception($"Cannot connect to {hostname} on port 21", ex);

                tc.Close();
            }
            throw new Exception($"Could connect to {hostname} on port 20 and 21", ex);
        }
        throw new Exception($"Could not ping {hostname}", ex);
    }
}
```

The new exception should be enough to make you realize of what is the issue.

- If you get an error like "Could not ping <something>", then hostname could be resolved but it's not reachable, you should check if the ftp is on a different network.
- If you get an error like "Cannot connect to `hostname` on port 20" or "Cannot connect to `ftpUrl` on port 21", the port is filtered, you should check if there is any firewall filtering it.

EDIT:
I just realized that in `ftpUrl` you're including something like "ftp://host/path". That explains why you get the "No such host is known".
So I just edited the code to avoid that.

Anyway from your comments, the FTP is running on the same server and checking the error you posted before (Unable to connect to the remote server), I guess it might be that the FTP site is stopped.

If that FTP site is stopped, just open the IIS manager (inetmgr), expand sites and make sure that the FTP site (it might have any name, you'll need to check the binding to confirm it's the FTP) is running, otherwise start it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the shared server to do any testing. And I got this error after using the code you provided: "_[Exception: Error pinging ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/: System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known_".

Comment: Even though `ftp.mywebsite.com` is a public domainname, it seems unknown for the server? Try with ip instead.

Comment: If trying @FrankNielsen's suggestion you keep having a similar error, set ftpUrl as google.com, to confirm if there is internet access from the server.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I tried changing the ftpUrl to IP but I got the same result.

Comment: @MarianoDemarchi I changed it to google.com and I got this error: _System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.217.3.110:21_

Comment: With the IP, does it says "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known" ? Else list the error..

Comment: google.com is not listening on the ftp port, so that error is legit

Comment: All what you explained seems to point to a connectivity issue between your server and the ftp endpoint. The ftp endpoint doesn't seem to be publicly available on internet. You'll have to fix it to make your code work. Of course the first step is to understand properly how your network infrastructure is set.

Comment: @FrankNielsen Yes, it still says "No such host is known".

Comment: @MarianoDemarchi But what if the web application and the ftp server are using the same IP address? Does this at all relate to the error that I'm encountering right now? I even tried changing the ftpUrl to `ftp://127.0.0.1` and `ftp://localhost` but still got the same error. I will try contacting web.com about this, but it takes so long for them to answer back.

Comment: _No such host is known_ is reported when a hostname is resolved through DNS, using a IP it should report _A connection attempt failed because the connected party...._ so whatever you are testing, be sure it is correct setup/configured - else everybody will be confused, and can not help.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry about that, I'm also just realizing it now. Could you please show me how to properly set up the configuration on my web app to connect to the localhost?

Comment: @FrankNielsen At this point, I'm not really sure what the correct configuration is. Could you please help me configure my web app with the information I've provided so far? Or is this still a connection issue between my web app and the ftp server?

Comment: @ramson48 please check my answer, I edited it yesterday.

Comment: @MarianoDemarchi I got a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 111.222.333.44:21`. So this is a server issue right? If that's the case, I really can't do anything but to wait for web.com to give me some answers.

Comment: Yes, it's the FTP configuration in the server. If you don't have remote access or you don't have a way to enable the FTP service from a configuration panel, you'll need the support from web.com.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that your FTP server is actually the same machine as your web server. So it's `localhost` in relation to the FTP server.

In general, there should not be any problem, when connecting to a localhost server. If it does not work, chances are that the provider explicitly forbids localhost connection (though it's strange). Are you really sure that the web server and FTP server are the same?

---

Anyway, it makes no sense to connect to a local machine using FTP. If you are on the machine directly, you can directly access the files – Those are local files. Use `System.IO` classes, like [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) or [`Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory) (specifically [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) or similar), not `FtpWebRequest`.